# Will Ubuntu phone edition work with snapdragon CPUs?

Tags: phone

I have been following the project for a while now and I have been refurbishing PCs with Ubuntu for years now. Because of what I've seen of Ubuntu, I would love to see it go further into the mobile world. Does anyone know what CPUs will be supported? All the official page says for the supercomputer edition is a cortex a9 or atom.

Answer (score 0):

Whne it is finally released (it will hopefully be the same image for both phone and computer)it it will almost definitely support snapdragon and many well known arm based chipsets, I don't know about exynos chips but maybe it'll support them too. I wouldn't count on it running on older phones but I expect it will support the current flagships from most major vendors, all the way back to phones with chipsets like the snapdragon 400 or even earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **Ubuntu Touch** and the compatibility with **SnapDragon CPUs**, according to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices#Working_with_ubuntu-device-flash) Wiki, the **developer** version supports **Nexus 4**, for example, which has a SnapDragon CPU